# Can I sell the GDPR data I requested?

Tags: gdpr

If I request to download my personal data under GDPR, from sites like Google or Facebook, is it legal for me to sell that data?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is data about you you can sell it, if anyone wants to buy it, or give it away as you might choose.